# Securing API EndPoints with JWT (JSON Web Token)

Tags: vue.js, cakephp, cakephp-3.x, jwt

**Edited with additional info : error still there..**

I am developing an application with CakePHP BackEnd and Vue FrontEnd and am in the process of securing my API BackEnd with JWT Security. For this I am using the 'ADmad/JwtAuth.Jwt' Plugin, but I believe you do not need to know this plugin to be able to answer the question. Basic idea is that upon login/ register, the client receives a JWT token, stores it in cookies/ session, and then uses it in subsequent requests to the API.

The plugin is loaded in my AppController, my API secret is stored in app.php..

```php
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'storage' => 'Memory',
            'authenticate' => [
                'ADmad/JwtAuth.Jwt' => [
                    'parameter' => 'token',
                    'userModel' => 'Users',
                    'fields' => [
                        'email' => 'id'
                    ],

                    'queryDatasource' => true
                ]
            ],
            'checkAuthIn' => 'Controller.initialize',
        ]);
```

When logging in, through form/ facebook, or registering, the JWT is generated and sent to the client. I will illustrate this through the login action, facebook login & register are built up similarly. These are allowed actions on the UsersController, the rest are protected by JWT Auth Plugin..

```php
$this->Auth->allow(['login', 'register', 'facebooklogin', 'getfbcredentials']);
```

On the client side (Vue), the function loginUser takes email/ password credentials from the form and sends them to the API. On the server-side (Cake API) the hashed password is checked with value in DB and the mail/ password credentials, along with an expiration date, are sent back encrypted with api secret from environment variables on server side.

On the client-side these credentials are decrypted and compared to original mail/ password values to make sure no outside attacker has tampered with them. Only then login is allowed and token is stored in a cookie..

I am not 100% sure if it is better to store them in a cookie or sessionstorage, but httponly cookie seemed the same and I have chosen this option because I have read arguments for and against both..
https://dzone.com/articles/cookies-vs-tokens-the-definitive-guide

Client-side Vue fetch interaction..

```js
methods: {
    
    loginUser(){
        
        this.errors = "";
        
        // if one of the mandatory fields is empty 
        if(!this.email || !this.password){
            
            this.errors = "fill in all fields with an *";
            
        // make the API call     
        } else {
            
            // cannot use associative arrays in Javascript : does not exist!! 
            this.data[0] = this.email;
            this.data[1] = this.password;            

            fetch(this.$baseURL + '/users/login', {
              method: 'POST',
              mode: 'cors',
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              },
              body: JSON.stringify(this.data),
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json_data => {
                
                // console.log(json_data);
                
                // wrong password
                if(json_data == 2){
                    
                    this.errors = "wrong password, please correct."      
                    this.password = ""; 
                    
                // email not found     
                } else if (json_data == 0){
                    
                    this.errors = "email not registered, please register.."    
                
                // succesful save     
                } else if (json_data[0] == 1) {
                            
                    // perform JWT token check, store it & use it in subsequent API calls.. 
                    var payload = this.parseJwt(json_data[2]);                  
                                
                    this.$session.set('isLogged', true); 
                    this.$session.set('user', json_data[1]);
                    this.$session.set('navigateto', 'userhub'); 
                    this.$emit('navEvent');

                    this.errors = "welcome!" 
                    this.email = this.password = "";   

                    // (XSFR attack vulnerability cookie, protected through CORS :: XSS no vulnerability with cookie) 
                    this.$cookies.set('jwtoken', json_data[2], {httpOnly: true});
                            
                }
                
            })
            .catch(error => {

                // console.log("error");
                this.errors = "no success.. please try again."  

            });                        
        }
    },
```

API-side (Cake) interaction, login action UsersController:

```php
// loginaction needs to be the same, is defined in AppController 
public function login(){

    $data = $this->request->data; 
    $sendback = [];
    $hasher = new DefaultPasswordHasher();
    
    // no automatic view, only data returned
    $this->autoRender = false;        
    
    // mandatory check to prevent server timeout 
    if($data){
              
        $users = $this->Users->find('all');
        
        foreach($users as $user):

            if ($user['email'] === $data[0]){

                if ($hasher -> check($data[1], $user['password'])){

                    // get user id, this is the user given you implement a check for double entries 
                    // never a password in storage!!!! 
                    $user['password'] = "";
                    $user['resetcode'] = "";
                    
                    // JWT Encode the payload/ secret to generate token..
                    // secret from environment variables, not known to the attacker, needs to know this to form the token or steal the token.. 
                    $apisecret = Configure::read('apisecret');  
                    $payload = ['mail' => $data[0], 'password' => $data[1],'exp' =>  time() + 604800, 'id' => $user['id'], 'sub' => $user['id']];
                    
                    // uses salt value in app.php for encryption::encryption mechanism uses firebase library combined with salt value..  
                    $jwt = JWT::encode([$payload, $apisecret], Security::salt());
                    
                    $sendback[0] = 1;
                    $sendback[1] = $jwt;

                // wrong password 
                } else {

                    $sendback[0] = 2;

                }
                
                // break actually does the same as a $this->Users->find('first') with condition email.. 
                // break the loop whenever email is found, run password check 1 time.. 
                break;                    

            } else {

                $sendback[0] = 0;

            }

        endforeach;        
        
    }   
         
    return $this->response
    ->withType('application/json')
    ->withStringBody(json_encode($sendback));              
                
}
```

So far so good.. :-)
Now I want to use this cookie in subsequent API requests to my Back-End. So I am setting my JWT, retrieved from my cookie, in Authorization Header in my fetch request.. I am getting an error on my Back-End, stating "You are not authorized to access that location". (Error log bottom page)..

```js
fetch(this.$baseURL + '/holidays', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.$cookies.get("jwtoken"),
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(this.data),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json_data => {
        
        // console.log(json_data);
        
    })
    .catch(error => {

        this.errors = "no success.. please try again."

    });
```

Error Log

```
2020-09-29 11:44:14 Error: [Cake\Http\Exception\UnauthorizedException] You are not authorized to access that location. (C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\admad\cakephp-jwt-auth\src\Auth\JwtAuthenticate.php:264)
#0 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Controller\Component\AuthComponent.php(387): ADmad\JwtAuth\Auth\JwtAuthenticate->unauthenticated(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#1 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Controller\Component\AuthComponent.php(315): Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent->_unauthenticated(Object(App\Controller\UsersController))
#2 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Event\EventManager.php(352): Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent->authCheck(Object(Cake\Event\Event))
#3 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Event\EventManager.php(329): Cake\Event\EventManager->_callListener(Array, Object(Cake\Event\Event))
#4 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Event\EventDispatcherTrait.php(113): Cake\Event\EventManager->dispatch(Object(Cake\Event\Event))
#5 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Controller\Controller.php(676): Cake\Controller\Controller->dispatchEvent('Controller.init...')
#6 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\ActionDispatcher.php(115): Cake\Controller\Controller->startupProcess()
#7 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\ActionDispatcher.php(94): Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->_invoke(Object(App\Controller\UsersController))
#8 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\BaseApplication.php(234): Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#9 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(65): Cake\Http\BaseApplication->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#10 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware.php(162): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#11 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(65): Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#12 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware.php(88): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#13 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(65): Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#14 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php(96): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#15 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(65): Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#16 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\debug_kit\src\Middleware\DebugKitMiddleware.php(53): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#17 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(65): DebugKit\Middleware\DebugKitMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#18 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(51): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#19 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Server.php(97): Cake\Http\Runner->run(Object(Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue), Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#20 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\webroot\index.php(40): Cake\Http\Server->run()
#21 {main}
Request URL: /users/retrievepicture
Referer URL: http://localhost:8080/
```

What am I doing wrong in using my JSON Web Token? I think there is an error in my Authorization Header, but unsure.. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

From Packege [Documentation](https://github.com/ADmad/cakephp-jwt-auth) and a simple but good explaining [tutorial](https://www.bravo-kernel.com/2015/04/how-to-add-jwt-authentication-to-a-cakephp-3-rest-api/) I suggest you add

```
'storage' => 'Memory',
'checkAuthIn' => 'Controller.initialize',
```

in your **$this->loadComponent('Auth',...)**

Also when you are creating token , add **user-id**, **sub** in payload like this

```
payload = ['id' => $user['id'],'sub' => $user['id'] ,'mail' => $data[0], 'password' => $data[1],'exp' =>  time() + 3600];
```

Also requesting you to follow the above tutorial link to understand better.

Edit: if this problem still exist, please

- check whether Vue is sending the Token in API request
- For debugging, Auth allow that method which is bind /holidays request to  and check header by

  $header = $request->getHeaderLine('Authorization');
- print the $header in the controller method to see if CakePHP receives the Authorization Header.

Comment: Hello Kaiser Ahmed Tushar, thank you for your reply. I have implemented your suggestions and I still get the same error message but no further details. Is there anything else that could be causing this? Have edited in the question..

Comment: Hello, after your edit in the question I also add some note in my answer in the end. Please let me know the output. Also provide the JWT token.

Comment: It still does not work.. I decided to work around the Plugin & write some functions myself for encoding/ decoding the token. This solution works fine. If you want I can share the code with you..

Comment: If solution works then we don't need to worry. Happy coding.